# Selenium throws "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException" in C# program

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm programming Selenium using C#, but I don't understand how to use it.
For example, I want to check the XPath that I want to click from HTML.
This is the HTML I want.

```
<span class="option_text">10</span>
```

Below is the original HTML

```
<div class="report_options _options">
<a href="#" class="option" data-reportpolicy="R1">
    <i class="ico as_radio"></i>
        <span class="option_text">1</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="option" data-reportpolicy="R2">
    <i class="ico as_radio"></i>
      <span class="option_text">2</span>
</a>
.
.(Omitted)
.
<a href="#" class="option" data-reportpolicy="R11">
    <i class="ico as_radio"></i>
        <span class="option_text">10</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I used

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'option_text') and contains(text(), '10')]")).Click();
```

but I could not. How can I fix this?

PS. Visual Studio error log:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no
>   such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='report-question-layer']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a[10]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)'

Comment: xpath //*[@id='report-question-layer']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a[10] is failing as per error not //span[contains(@class,'option_text') and contains(text(), '10')]

Comment: as per your error log, the error is on different line of code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CGe6xh5J
Im sorry, the one I wrote above is different because I copied it before.
I want to share a link, but login is required on a Japanese web page.
I posted all of the elements in Japanese to Pastebin.
please look ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below XPATH :-

```
//a[@class='option' and @data-reportpolicy='R11']//span[@class='option_text']
```

OR

```
//*[@id="report-question-layer"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a[10]/span
```

OR

```
//div[@id='report-question-layer']//div[@class='report_options _options']//a[@data-reportpolicy='R11']/span
```

OR

```
//a[@data-reportpolicy='R11']/span
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. However, neither of them did live well.Unable to locate element

Comment: It is because as per your error the another xpath is breaking not the above one which you have posted. Can you share link where you need xpath.

Comment: I am sorry, what I wrote above is what I put out at another time.
I'd like to share a link, but I need a login on the Japanese WEB page.

Comment: Can you upload a link having the page source of your page. That HTML Dom will help us to extract xpath for you

Comment: From about line 1410.
The element I want is the 1434 th line "その他の禁止されている行為".
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhOAWO4frEdrgcQLfQ4HK0_nW1XkfQ

Comment: As per the document I have extract some of the XPath .. Please try them and add the latest error if you got any

Comment: I could move it.:) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checking in the HTML, You can try to use this way:

First, try to switch to the frame:
`WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("fb_xdm_frame_https")));`

Then try the following XPath to click on it:
`WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'その他の禁止されている行為')]")).Click();`

Comment: thank you for answering. However, it did not work well.TT

Comment: Do you know if there's any IFRAME on your page? That might dificult the way to click in the element.